# Safari and media query for mobile

Tags: safari, media-queries

If anyone have some ideas about this will be nice to hear some.
I did have done a Responsive Website which works pretty well with IE, Firefox and Chrome.
But when i browse it with Safari (same with all the version), it seams that Safari catch the MOBILE media query instead of the one i define.

Check it out : [www.lpfilmfest.org](http://www.lpfilmfest.org)

Any help would be appreciate.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your stylesheet, main.css, the first 2 media queries are each missing their closing curly-brace. This is causing them to nest and be misinterpreted by Safari. In the formatted CSS:

1. after line 980 add, }
2. and after line 1227 add, }